# Please commit your changes or stash them before you switch branches

Tags: git

I have two branch

- dev
- feature

Unconsciously I have written some code in dev branch that are not allowed in dev branch without testing. I don't want to loss all the code that I have written. Now I want to switch feature branch and added all changed files in feature branch. But when I want to checkout feature branch it shows

```
Please commit your changes or stash them before you switch branches
```

There is any way to switch feature branch and get all changed files in feature branch so that i add those file in feature branch.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+Please+commit+your+changes+or+stash+them+before+you+switch+branches

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As git is telling you, you can either commit the changes or stash them.

The easiest solution here is to stash them:

```
# Assuming you are on dev branch
$ git stash save "Code in dev branch to be included in feature branch"
$ git checkout feature
$ git stash pop
```

your changes are now available in `feature`.